# move_uploaded_file function equivalent in django

Tags: python, django, redirect, file-upload, cloud-hosting

I would like to upload some files from form to cloud server without redirecting there. So I've found [this](http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-file-upload-tutorial.html) tutorial with php/ajax but a function that is not present in django is used there - `move_uploaded_file`. How can I achieve the same with django ? Currently I'm using a part of django-filetransfers, but after submitting my form the whole part after `if request.method == POST` is omitted :

```
def upload_handler(request):            
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ArtifactSubmissionForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:    
        upload_url, upload_data = prepare_upload(request, "uploadlink")
        form = ArtifactSubmissionForm()    

    myfileid = create_myfileid()
    return direct_to_template(request, 'rte/artifact_inline.html',
        {'upload_url': upload_url,
        'form': form,
        'upload_data': upload_data,
        'myfileid': myfileid,
        'artifact': artifact,
        'submissions': submissions})
```

and the html:

```
{% load filetransfers %}

{% block artifact %}
<h1>Submit</h1>
<form action="{{ upload_url }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% render_upload_data upload_data %}
    <table>{{ form }}</table>    
    <p>
        <input type="hidden" maxlength="64" name="myfileid" value="{{ myfileid }}" >
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

---

EDIT:

I just need to send files to server for further processing and then read their urls from servers response. Don't need to use them as File objects.

Comment: At a glance, that PHP tutorial is just moving the files on the server that received them. It's probably not useful for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The django-storages plug-in has features that allows you to automatically store uploaded content to the repository of your choice.  It has an annoying need to be linked to your MEDIA_URL, but that's just code and you can work around it.

Source code can be found here: [Django storages](http://code.welldev.org/django-storages/wiki/Home).

I recommend rooting around the network for one that you like.  If you're using Amazon Cloudfront, as I do at my current position, using one that disabls HTTPS over signed URLS saved us a few millicents per download, which does add up over time.

Comment: I'm not using S3. Also django-storages only allows to send files via ftp - small files. Guess I need to write it from scratch.

Comment: If they're very large files, you have two problems: consistency and response time.  In circumstances like those, I would (1) have an alternative server doing nothing but handling file transfers and (2) launch tasks with celery or gearman to transfer the data to its final repository.